# Quantization of Light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light

Why Vs will not change with different intensity, I mean why more photoelectrons emitted (at higher light intensity) each with the same max K. E. doesn't require a larger stopping potential to be stopped since the KE added from each e would be larger?

Answer (score 0):

There is a constant force on every photoelectron emitted because of light when stopping potential is applied. Increasing intensity will only increase the number of photo electrons emitted. When a stopping potential is applied, same amlunt of force is applied on all the electrons irrespective of the no. Of photoelectrons emitted. The extra work will be done by the battery which is the source of voltage to balance the extra kinetic energy. But there is no need to increase the voltage of battery.